# Gmail api returns 404 error when calling message.get

Tags: gmail-api

Gmail API history.list is returning messageId's that return 404 when message.get is called.

I call history.list with "INBOX" label and "history/messagesAdded" fields.  I then call message.get with each of the messageId's returned. Some of them return valid messages, others return the following exception:

```
Google_Service_Exception
{
   "error": {
   "errors": [
   {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "notFound",
     "message": "Not Found"
    }
   ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

What would cause this? It seems like we just retrieved the messageId there isn't enough time for them to now be permanently deleted.

Comment: If you also get the fields `history/messagesDeleted` and `history/labelsRemoved` you will probably see that these messages have been removed.

Comment: They will appear in both `history/messagesAdded` and `history/messagesDeleted` for the same call?

Comment: Yes. You will get the history from the `historyId` given up until now, so if the message has been added to the inbox and deleted since `historyId`, the same `messageId` will appear in both `history/messagesAdded` and `history/messagesDeleted`.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, this can happen if the message was deleted. This can be checked in the **messagesDeleted** array return by **gmail's history.list**, just make sure you send the appropriate `historyTypes` (or doesn't send any at all).

```
{
 "history": [
  {
   "id": "69014",
   "messagesAdded": [
    {
     "message": {
      "id": "165a2cd1a5b308b9",
      "threadId": "1659e85b88e80e7b",
     }
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "69024",
   "messagesDeleted": [
    {
     "message": {
      "id": "165a2cd1a5b308b9",
      "threadId": "1659e85b88e80e7b",
     }
    }
   ]
  }
}
```